# How to get newly created node ID after Feeds importing?

Tags: nodes, feeds, importing-exporting

I programmatically executed feeds importer to create new nodes. I have to set some fields programmatically after importing. I check the hooks in feeds.api.php, and didn't find a solution. Is there any way that I can get the newly created node ID by the importer? 
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. Use $entity NOT $entity_id in hook_feeds_after_save.